# terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc what: std::bad_alloc Aborted

Tags: python, c++, c++17, cython, cythonize

I have wrapped a C++ library into Cython and called from Python, but facing the error.

**EntryPoint.cpp**

```
#include "EntryPoint.h"
#include "../CoSiteAPI/CoSiteAPI.h"
int CheckSeriell(std::string StreamNameS,std::string StreamNameG,std::string StreamNameR, int na)
{
    return CoSiteAPI::APIMethod_CheckSeriell(StreamNameS, StreamNameG, StreamNameR, na);
}
```

**EntryPointCy.pyx**

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "EntryPoint.h":
    cpdef int CheckSeriell(string StreamNameS,string StreamNameG,string StreamNameR, int na);
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = Extension(name="EntryPointNew", sources=["EntryPointCy.pyx"], language="c++", extra_objects=["EntryPoint.a", "CoSiteAPI.a", "BeSpokeCalculator.a", "BeSpokeInterface.a", "GeoCalculator.a", "libtbb.a"])
setup(name='EntryPointNew', ext_modules=cythonize(extensions), cmdclass={'build_ext':build_ext})
```

**test.py**

```
import EntryPointNew
var1 = b"../Daten/StationAdaptiert_Check_1.json"
var2 = b"../Daten/GegenStationAdaptiert.json"
var3 = b"../Daten/ReUsePlanCoSiteHF.json"
var4 = 10000
result = EntryPointNew.CheckSeriell(var1,var2,var3,var4);
print("Result: ", result)
```

Finally, I am entering following commands to run the codes.

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
python3 test.py
```

*setup.py* file compiles successfully, and I get *.so* file. However, *test.py* file produces following error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Can anyone give some hints about possible reasons of this error? Thanks.

Comment: There is a bug in you c++ code (which we don’t see by the way)

Comment: You probably want a c++ exception specification for the Cython wrapping of `CheckSeriell` (e.g. `except +`) so that Cython catches the error rather than fails. But we can't know where the error is coming from.

Comment: Your are right @ead . From test.py, I was passing the file name. Instead, I should have read the file and pass its content as a string. Since C++ code was not getting the correct string, that is why it was producing error.